# Tablesorter: External Checkbox to Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, tablesorter

I'm trying to use an external checkbox to filter the table based on the contents of a column. The only related questions/solutions I've found are dealing with checkboxes inside the table used for sorting purposes.

**Desired Functionality:** For the sake of simplicity, let's say column 4 contains either a 0 or 1. When this external checkbox is checked, I'd like it to filter the results (where column 4 contains the value 1).

**Working Alternative:** When using an external select (dropdown), I can achieve the desired functionality. The select element (`<select id="test_select" name="test_select" class="search" data-column="4">`) has an option (`<option value="1">1</option>`) and then, inside the "widgetOptions" configuration, have `filter_external: '.search'`.

But a having a select with one option doesn't make sense as far as usability is concerned.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the ["search" method](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#method-search) to perform any queries on the table data.

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/r25tag6k/11/)

HTML

```
<label><input id="findzeroes" type="checkbox"> Find Zeroes</label>
```

Script

```
$(function() {

  $('#findzeroes').on('change', function(){
    var query = [];
    if (this.checked) {
      // target 4th column (zero-based index)
      query[3] = '0';
    }
    $('table').trigger('search', [ query ]);
  });

  $('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
  });
});
```

Using a `<select>` instead of a checkbox will also work.

Comment: That's perfect! Worked like a charm. As always, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to turn a multiple column filter on and off with a checkbox, but found @Mottie's answer didn't do the trick because it doesn't allow for `filter_external` and `data-column="7,8"` type filtering.

So I just created a hidden field which has the `data-column="7,8"` attribute and use jQuery to change its value when the checkbox is changed, and also to trigger a keyup event.

```
$('#checkboxId').on('change', function(){
    var filterTerm = $(this).prop('checked') ? '?' : ''
    $('#hiddenFieldId').val(filterTerm).keyup() 
})
```

I use a filter value of '?' which is a non space character, that could be anything you'd type into a normal filter field.